# Zoom in/out using ctrl+mouse wheel in CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to enable or implement the functionality zoom in/out using the combination ctrl+mouse wheel on CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer?

MouseWheel is used to scroll. A suggested idea could be handle mouseevent, abort scroll and adjust zoom using delta... but I'm not able to handle the mousewheel event.

I have try handle CrystalReportViewer.MouseWheel, it compile but never raised. I have also try to inherit the control CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer and override OnMouseWheel method and it is never called. Any idea?

Comment: You can use the MouseWheel event's delta to adjust the CrystalReportViewer's zoom factor, give it a try

Comment: I cannot handle MouseWheel event. I have try handle CrystalReportViewer.MouseWheel, it compile but never raised. I have also try to inherit the control CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer and override OnMouseWheel method and it is never called. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852824/usercontrol-how-to-add-mousewheel-listener). Then I have solved my problem implementing IMessageFilter interface to intercept MouseWheel message when Ctrl key is pressed. I processed the message before the CrystalReportViewer control and adjusted zoom level according to delta.
I post my solution, hope this could be useful to other.
Let me know If you find a better solution or a bug.

```
Imports System.Drawing
'Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Public Class CrystalReportViewerMouseWheelZoom
    Implements IMessageFilter

    Private WithEvents _viewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
    Private _viewerForm As Form = Nothing
    Private _ZoomLevel As Integer
    Public Sub New(viewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer)
        Me._viewer = viewer
        Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub _viewer_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _viewer.Disposed
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(Me)
        _viewer = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub _viewer_ViewZoom(source As Object, e As ZoomEventArgs) Handles _viewer.ViewZoom
        _ZoomLevel = e.NewZoomFactor
    End Sub

    '<DllImport("user32.dll")>
    'Private Shared Function WindowFromPoint(ByVal p As Point) As IntPtr
    'End Function

    Private Const ZOOM_LEVEL_DELTA_PERC As Double = 5D
    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        If (m.Msg <> &H20A) Then Return False

        If Not My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then Return False

        Dim mouseAbsolutePosition = New Point(m.LParam.ToInt32())
        Dim mouseRelativePosition = _viewer.PointToClient(mouseAbsolutePosition)


        'DOEW NOT WORK, Control.FromHandle return always null
        'Dim hControlUnderMouse As IntPtr = WindowFromPoint(mouseAbsolutePosition)
        'Dim controlUnderMouse = Control.FromHandle(hControlUnderMouse)
        'If Not Equals(controlUnderMouse, _viewer) Then Return False
        If Not IsViewerFormActive() Then Return False

        Dim _documentControl = FindFirstDocumentControl(_viewer)
        If _documentControl Is Nothing Then Return False
        Dim screenRectangle = _documentControl.RectangleToScreen(_documentControl.ClientRectangle)
        If Not screenRectangle.Contains(mouseAbsolutePosition) Then Return False

        Dim delta = m.WParam.ToInt32() >> 16
        Dim newZoomLevel As Integer = CalcNewZoomLevel(_documentControl, delta)
        If (newZoomLevel < 3) Then Return False

        _viewer.Zoom(newZoomLevel)
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function IsViewerFormActive() As Boolean
        Dim active As Boolean = False
        If _viewerForm Is Nothing Then _viewerForm = _viewer.FindForm
        Dim activeForm = Form.ActiveForm
        If activeForm IsNot Nothing AndAlso activeForm.IsMdiContainer AndAlso _viewerForm.IsMdiChild Then
            active = Equals(activeForm.ActiveMdiChild, _viewerForm)
        Else
            active = Equals(activeForm, _viewerForm)
        End If
        Return active
    End Function

    Private Function CalcNewZoomLevel(_documentControl As DocumentControl, delta As Integer) As Integer
        Dim newZoomLevel = _ZoomLevel

        If newZoomLevel < 3 Then
            Dim rpt = TryCast(_viewer.ReportSource, ReportDocument)
            If rpt Is Nothing Then Return -1

            Using g = _viewer.CreateGraphics()
                If _ZoomLevel = 1 Then
                    newZoomLevel = CInt((_documentControl.ClientSize.Width / GetPageWith(rpt, g)) * 100)
                ElseIf _ZoomLevel = 2 Then
                    newZoomLevel = CInt((_documentControl.ClientSize.Height / GetPageHeight(rpt, g)) * 100)
                End If
            End Using

        End If


        newZoomLevel += (If(delta < 0, -1, 1) * CInt(newZoomLevel * ZOOM_LEVEL_DELTA_PERC / 100))
        Return newZoomLevel
    End Function

    Private Function GetPageHeight(rpt As ReportDocument, g As Graphics) As Integer
        Dim twips = rpt.PrintOptions.PageContentHeight + rpt.PrintOptions.PageMargins.topMargin + rpt.PrintOptions.PageMargins.bottomMargin
        Return CInt(CDbl(twips) * (1.0 / 1440.0) * g.DpiY)
    End Function

    Private Function GetPageWith(rpt As ReportDocument, g As Graphics) As Integer
        Dim twips = rpt.PrintOptions.PageContentWidth + rpt.PrintOptions.PageMargins.leftMargin + rpt.PrintOptions.PageMargins.rightMargin
        Return CInt(CDbl(twips) * (1.0 / 1440.0) * g.DpiX)
    End Function

    Private Function FindFirstDocumentControl(parent As Control) As DocumentControl
        Dim docCrtl As DocumentControl = Nothing
        For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf c Is DocumentControl Then
                docCrtl = DirectCast(c, DocumentControl)
                Exit For
            Else
                docCrtl = FindFirstDocumentControl(c)
            End If
            If docCrtl IsNot Nothing Then Exit For
        Next
        Return docCrtl
    End Function
End Class
```